# Jquery Key And Value

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
{
    "clientIds": [{ 
        "id": 0,
        "clientId": "check123"
    }]
}
```

The above is json object. How to split this into key value? I got key is: clientIds
but value comes object I want  check123 value and append in dropdown using jquery how to divide and append in dropdown.

Comment: clientIds[0].clientId

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `clientId` and `Id` as

```js
var a = {"clientIds":[{"id":0,"clientId":"check123"}]};
alert(a.clientIds[0].clientId);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To take the object and turn it into options in a select menu do the following.

```
for(var i = 0; i < clientIds.length; i++){
   $('#dropdown').append($('<option />').val(clientIds[i].id)).text(clientIds[i].clientId));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `clientIds` is an array, iterate over it.

```
 var data = {"clientIds":[{"id":0,"clientId":"check123"}]};
 $.each(data, function(index, element) {
    var id = element.id; // will have the value 0
     var clientId = element.clientId; // will have the value check123
 });
```

Once you got these, build your dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

```
   var a = {"clientIds":[{"id":0,"clientId":"check123"}]};
       $.each( a.clientIds,function () {
          $('#dropdown').append($('<option />').val($(this).id)).text($(this).clientId);
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var a = {"clientIds":[{"id":0,"clientId":"check123"}]};
for(i=0;i<a.clientIds.length;i++)
    $('#myoptions').append($('<option value="'+a.clientIds[i].id+'">'+a.clientIds[i].clientId+'</option>'));
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/saz7Lf3g/)